# Menu organization appears to be random

Tags: bug, android-app

When using the android app the menu organization of all the sites I have pinned appears to be random and not in the same order that I have them pinned on the website or iOs Version. I have tried to edit the list to get it to sync up and show in the proper order but that is not fixing it.

When I am in the list to edit the sites it is showing up there in the correct order but when I save the changes it goes back to the random order and not showing them in the expected order.

Comment: It is probably sorted by unicorns ...

Comment: From what I can see in the suggested duplicates it is sorted like a string instead of numerically sorted. As an example 0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 1, 20 ........ It seems that this should be looked into again in order to provide better usability to people who use multiple devices and sites.